# VBA Macro not Execute .bat file

Tags: vba, excel

Batch file can be executed manually, but when I try and execute from a macro in Excel I'm getting a "Run-time error '5' Invalid procedure call or argument" on the line `Call Shell(stAppName, 1)`. Here is my code:

```
Private Sub run_Click()
    Const DELIMITER As String = "," 'or "|", vbTab, etc.
    Dim myRecord As Range
    Dim myField As Range
    Dim nFileNum As Long
    Dim sOut As String

    nFileNum = FreeFile
    Open "C:\apps\Test.bat" For Output As #nFileNum
    For Each myRecord In Range("B20:B24")
        With myRecord
            For Each myField In Range(.Cells(1), _
                    Cells(.Row, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
                sOut = sOut & DELIMITER & myField.Text
            Next myField
            Print #nFileNum, Mid(sOut, 2)
            sOut = Empty
        End With
    Next myRecord
    Close #nFileNum

Dim stAppName As String

stAppName = "cmd.exe /k c:\apps\test.bat"
Call Shell(stAppName, 1)

End Sub
```

Comment: You should post your code as text

Comment: Please don't post a screenshot of your code. Instead, copy your code into the question and format it as a code block. It's both faster for you and it makes life easier for us since we can test out the code ourselves. http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: I'm not certain you actually have to call cmd.exe directly.  You should just be able to run the batch file.  Otherwise you can use the shellexecute API.

Comment: Transcribed the code (painstakingly)

Comment: Why not just `Shell("c:\apps\test.bat", 1)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing

```
stAppName = "cmd.exe /k c:\apps\test.bat"
```

To

```
 stAppName = "c:\apps\test.bat"
```